# How to get the preset value of textbox to another texbox

Tags: javascript

Please I need your help. Am trying to get a preset value of a textbox into another textbox using document.getElementById. With my code, I can only get the value of whatever I typed, not the initial ROS I preset the textbox with. pls help

See my code below

```
    <input id="program" name="program1" size="40px" value="ROS" onblur="if(this.value==''){ 
    this.value='ROS';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='ROS'){ this.value='';}" onkeyup="Program();">

    <input type= "text" id = "program2" readonly size="50px" class="textbox-modal">

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Preview" class="button" onclick="Program()" />

    function Program() 
      {
      document.getElementById('program2').value = document.getElementById('program').value;
      }
```

Comment: you have code `onfocus="if(this.value=='ROS'){ this.value='';}` which means once you click or put your cursor into input 1, it will set the input value to empty `""`.

Comment: Yes, just to clear the textbox in case I want to type something different from ROS. But what I want is, if what I want is ROS, I dont need to type it anymore, I just want to call the  value to the next textbox without retyping ROS.

I dont know how to do it, Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution

```js
const firstInput = document.getElementById('program'),
  secondInput = document.getElementById('program2');
secondInput.value = 'ROS';

function Program() {
  secondInput.value = firstInput.value;
}

function handleBlur() {
  if (!firstInput.value) {
    secondInput.value = firstInput.value = 'ROS';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="program" name="program1" size="40px" value="ROS" onblur="handleBlur()" onfocus="if(this.value=='ROS'){ this.value='';};" onkeyup="Program();">

<input type="text" id="program2" readonly size="50px" class="textbox-modal">

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Preview" class="button" onclick="Program()" />
```

**Some details**

**1**.Initially set the value (ROS) for second input and again assign value to second input in `onblur` event if first input is empty.

**2**.You can also check if value is empty like this `if (!firstInput.value)`
This is equivalent of

```
if (firstInput.value == '' || firstInput.value == undefined || firstInput.value == null)
```

**Update (With Numerical values)**

It works as expected (See the example below).

```js
const firstInput = document.getElementById('day1'),
      secondInput = document.getElementById('day2');

secondInput.value = '0';

function Day1() {
  secondInput.value = firstInput.value;
}

function handleDay1Blur() {
  if (!firstInput.value) {
    secondInput.value = firstInput.value = '0';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="day1" size="40px" value="0" onblur="handleDay1Blur()" 
onfocus="if (this.value==0) { this.value=''; };" onkeyup="Day1();">

<input type="text" id="day2" readonly size="40px" class="textbox-modal">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Preview" class="button" onclick="Day1()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please am back again. I want to use the above code for numeric values but its not getting the right value, it keeps returning 0. How can I do this? See my usage below.

```
const firstInput = document.getElementById('day1'),
      secondInput = document.getElementById('day2');

secondInput.value = '0';

function Day1() {
  secondInput.value = firstInput.value;
}

function handleDay1Blur() {
  if (!firstInput.value) {
    secondInput.value = firstInput.value = '0';
  }
}

<input id="day1" size="40px" value="0" onblur="handleBlur()" 
onfocus="if (this.value==0) { this.value=''; };" onkeyup="Day1();">

<input type="text" id="day2" readonly size="40px" class="textbox-modal">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Preview" class="button" onclick="Day1()">
```

Comment: You should have edited your question, instead of asking in new answer.

Comment: Your function name doesn't match `handleBlur()` and `handleDay1Blur()`, What do you mean by **it keeps returning 0**

Comment: The function name is handleDay1Blur().....the other one was a mistake while typing the question.

What I mean by "It keeps returning 0.is: if i type 2 in textbox day1, textbox day2 will still be 0 instead of 2

Comment: So where do you get `0` ? as you said `it keeps returning 0`.

Comment: What I mean by "It keeps returning 0.is: if i type 2 in textbox day1, textbox day2 will still be 0 instead of 2

Comment: It works as expected..I have updated my answer with numerical values

Comment: Thanks Sameer Khan. Its now working, I was the one that made mistake in my naming flow.